# Adding require lightbox to application.js corrupts the delete method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, assets, lightbox

Can someone explain to me, why adding this:

```
require lightbox-bootstrap
```

Changes my "delete" method to "show" ??

This is my application.js:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
```

If I put require ("lightbox-bootstrap") it works of course, but the question is, why is this line only corrupting the delete method link and change it to show?

Comment: thx for downvoting :-* I know i have to put: require ("lightbox-bootstrap"). But i want to know why its corrupting only the delete-method and nothing else

Answer (score 1):

In this case, method `delete` in the link_to helper depend on `@rails/ujs"`, if you puts `require lightbox-bootstrap` i cause an error, so `@rails/ujs"` cannot load, it makes link_to work not correctly.